# Why is the IF statement not working? Class object property = Range selection/cell issue

Tags: vba, excel

I got a strange issue... my if statement should work but somehow it still doesn't... I can't grasp what is wrong as it seems perfectly right. I can see that the selection is targeting the last row in the A column, and then I'm comparing it to the t_date property in my EURO_USD object which is exactly the same string as in Column("A").End(xlDown), still, it jumps to the else statement(!). Why?

Code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub run() ' run the whole operation

Dim HTTP_Req As Object: Set HTTP_Req = New HTTP_Req
Dim EURO_USD As Object: Set EURO_USD = New EURO_USD
Sheets("EURO_USD").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Select

If Selection = EURO_USD.t_date Then
    Debug.Print "Date already exist"
    Else
        Sheets("EURO_USD").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = EURO_USD.t_date
End If

End Sub
```

EURO_USD Class below

```
Sub fetch() ' get the function o the ECB URL

Dim xDOM_nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim xDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

xDom.async = False
xDom.Load "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"

Do Until xDom.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

xDom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:f='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref' xmlns:c='http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01'"

Set xDOM_nodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("//f:Cube[@currency='USD']")
Curr_ticker = Val(xDOM_nodeList.Item(0).Attributes(1).text)

Set xDOM_nodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("//f:Cube[@time]")
Curr_date = xDOM_nodeList.Item(0).Attributes(0).text
End Sub

Public Property Get ticker()

If Curr_ticker = 0 Then
    Call fetch
    End If
ticker = Curr_ticker

End Property

Public Property Get t_date()

If Curr_date = "" Then
    Call fetch
    End If
t_date = Curr_date

End Property
```

Comment: Your t_Date property is returning a string - what is in the cell? A real date value? Is it formatted the same as the t_Date?

Comment: Ahh maybe that's the issue. The cell value is a date format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Rory

Your t_Date property is returning a string - what is in the cell? A real date value? Is it formatted the same as the t_Date?

Using function datevalue solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove **":"**

```
If Selection = EURO_USD.t_date Then
  Debug.Print "Date already exist"
Else
  Sheets("EURO_USD").Columns("A").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0) = EURO_USD.t_date
End If
```

Comment: Thank you. But it still does not solve the issue. It still jumps to the Else statement even thought selection and EURO_USD.t_date should be the same...

Comment: Yes Office. Excel 2013